# One-sided limit in topology

Tags: general-topology

Can we define One-sided limit in topology ? I think our space must be order set (Partially ordered set) . is it true?

Comment: "sided" (left and right) as well as maximun, minimun, bound and other concepts live in an order structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One would definitely need *some* order structure, otherwise the very notion of “sides” fails to make sense.

Here is an idea. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces and let $\succsim$ be a (say) partial order on $X$. Take any function $f:X\to Y$ and fix $x_0\in X$ and $y_0\in Y$. Let $$L_0\equiv\{x\in X\,|\,x_0\succsim x\}$$ be the “lower contour set” corresponding to $x_0$.

Now consider the following definition:

> The point $y_0$ is said to be a **lower limit of $f$ at $x_0$** if, whenever $(x_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in A}$ is a [net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)) (where $A$ is some non-empty, directed index set) such that
>
> - $x_{\alpha}\in L_0$ for all $\alpha\in A$, and
> - the net $(x_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in A}$ converges to $x_0$,
>
> then the corresponding net $(f(x_{\alpha}))_{\alpha\in A}$ in $Y$ converges to $y_0$.

Upper limits could be defined analogously.